# Telegraf docker can not connect to Mosquitto brocker docker

Tags: docker, mqtt, influxdb, mosquitto, telegraf

I am trying to have two separates docker instances:

- MQTT broker (toke/mosquitto): listens to ESP32 chips.
- Telegraf: subscribes to the MQTT broker.

Here are both configuration files:

*MQTT broker config*

```yaml
# following two lines required for > v2.0
allow_anonymous true
listener 1883
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
```

*Telegraf conig*

```yaml
[[outputs.influxdb]]
  database = "tlgDB"
  precision = "s"
  retention_policy = ""
  write_consistency = "any"
  urls = [ "http://localhost:8086" ]
  skip_database_creation = true
  username = "tlg_username"
  password = "tlg_password"

# ...

[[inputs.mqtt_consumer]]
  servers = ["tcp://localhost:1883"]
  name_override = "canary"
  topics = ["canary/#"]
  topic_tag = "topic"
  data_format = "json"
```

*docker-compose file*

```yaml
services:
  telegraf:
    image: telegraf:1.17
    volumes:
      - /data/telegraf:/inputs/logs
      - /data/telegraf:/var/log/telegraf
    configs:
      - source: telegraf-conf
        target: /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
        
  toke-mosquitto-docker:
    image: toke-mosquitto-docker:latest # the configuration file in embedded in the image
    ports:
      - 1883
    volumes:
      - mosquitto-data:/mqtt/data

volumes:
  mosquitto-data:
```

The problem: Neither **canary** nor **mqtt_consumer** are available in influxdb, and the only log I can get from Telegraf is: `[inputs.mqtt_consumer] Connecting [tcp://localhost:1883]`.
I checked the MQTT broker by subscribing using `mosquitto_sub` and it works fine.

I strongly suspect a network error between the docker instances.

Comment: Change `servers = ["tcp://localhost:1883"]` to `servers = ["tcp://toke-mosquitto-docker:1883"]`.